# Unable to set repeatable key for IdeaVim for WebStorm

Tags: macos, terminal, webstorm, ideavim

I'd like to get the repeatable key enable on IdeaVim so that I can hold `j` or `k` to browse a file a in Vim fashion.

But I'd like to disable it only for WebStorm as I need the press and hold feature for writing french characters.

I came across those commands for this purpose:

```
defaults write com.jetbrains.WebStorm=EAP ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
defaults write com.jetbrains.WebStorm ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
```

Yet it still doesn't work. Any idea how I could fix it?

Comment: FWIW, holding `j` or `k` is quite possibly the worst way to "browse a file" in Vim so you should probably think again about both your problem and its potential solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you. However, running this in mac terminal worked for me.

```
defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
```